# Headers and MIME types for HTML email messages (sending through PHP)

Tags: html, email, header, mime-types

What is the correct header information and MIME types for an email message with HTML content only, not mixed type (with both text and HTML).

Just to inform, I am using Swiftmailer (PHP) to this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code:

```
$swift = new stdClass();
$swift->transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance( '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs' );
$swift->mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance( $swift->transport );
$swift->message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Title')
    ->setFrom( array('from@my.email' => 'Me') )
    ->setTo( array( 'to@some.one' => 'Some One' ) )
    ->setBody('<h1>It works!</h1>', 'text/html');
```

You can also take a look at the Headers documentation on http://swiftmailer.org/docs/headers

Comment: I've done that, but it adds the contents of the message twice.

I try to insert the html code without 'text/html' and inserting mime headers after:

$headers = $message->getHeaders();

if ($headers->has('MIME-Version'))
{
 $MIME_Version = $headers->get('MIME-Version');
 $MIME_Version->setValue('1.0');
}
else
{
 $headers->addTextHeader('MIME-Version', '1.0');
}

if ($headers->has('Content-type'))
{
 $Content_type = $headers->get('Content-type');
 $Content_type->setValue('text/html');
}
else
{
 $headers->addTextHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
}

But incredibly the same error keeps happening

Comment: This is correct (in terms of programming), but the error still occurs